# Class not found with PSR-0

Tags: php, psr-0

I'm completely stuck on this issue! I'm using the [php-simple-html-dom-parser](https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser) and this is loaded with PSR-0. I'm not that familiar with PSR-0. But I use the class just as the readme file shows but I can't get it working.

In my IDE, autcompletion is working fine and not any error is shown. But when I run the script, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Sunra\PhpSimple\HtmlDomParser' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\test.php on line 3

Code:

```
<?php
use Sunra\PhpSimple\HtmlDomParser;
$dom = HtmlDomParser::file_get_html();
```

File structure:

```
folder\
  Sunra\
    PhpSimple\
      simplehtmldom_1_5\
      HtmlDomParser.php
test.php
```

As I said, I really have no idea what is going wrong. So probably I'm looking for the wrong thing and that's why I post this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/)

In your project directory run:

`php composer.phar require sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser ~1.5`

In your php file (index.php for example), add:

```
<?php

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Sunra\PhpSimple\HtmlDomParser;

$dom = HtmlDomParser::file_get_html();
```

Here, when you include `vendor/autoload.php` the composer generated autoloading configuration handles all class autoloads for you.  Nearly all libraries on github that follow PSR-0 exist on [Packagist](https://packagist.org/) making them available for install in this way.

You may want to read up on [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) to get an idea of what you are installing when you require libraries.

Most modern PHP frameworks now use Composer for their dependencies.  However it is still fully feasible for small projects of even a single file.

Comment: Well, I'd much rather have him understand what's an autoloader, than tell him "Just use this framework/tool/whatever and you'll do fine!"

Comment: Personally I tend to read the source of the tools I use.  If like me he finds this tech fascinating, reading the config composer generates will be a good lesson.

Comment: Oke, I will look into this. I'm not that familiar whith this stuff but as I'm developing myself I'm running into this problem more and more. So I will deep into this! Thanks

Comment: @Timo002 Read the installation instructions for the latest versions of Laravel and Symfony, they both use it.  Once you get the hang of it you can even create your own libraries to include via composer on other projects.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you aren't using an **[autoloader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)**, so the class will not be loaded automatically.

Here's a minimal **[autoloader example](https://gist.github.com/jwage/221634)** that uses PSR-0.

---

After you understand Autoloading, you should try and use dependency management frameworks like **Composer**. See **[Flosculus's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23673573/871050)** answer for more details.

Comment: I supposed the autoloader was delivered with the class itself

Comment: No, it's a separate component.

Comment: +1 for getting pointing our the actual problem, I know my solution was a bit of a side step.

Answer (score -1):

Using the PSR-0 autoloader, did you add it to a spl_autoload_register('autoload'), or are you using composer and included composers autoloader?

This works for me:

```
<?php
function autoload($className)
{
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

    require $fileName;
}
spl_autoload_register('autoload');

use Sunra\PhpSimple\HtmlDomParser;

$dom = HtmlDomParser::file_get_html('http://google.com');
var_dump($dom);
?>
```

Source: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/

Comment: -1. The use of `__autoload()` is no longer recommended.